# How to use coord_polar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following data frame in R and want to coord_polar chart out of it.

Below the structure of my data

```
dim(melted_TimingOfActivities)
[1] 181863      3

    l

library(ggplot2)



dput(head(melted_TimingOfActivities, 500))
structure(list(index = 1:500, variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("Personal care/sleep (mins per day)", "Employment (mins per day)", 
"Study (mins per day)", "Household & family care (mins per day)", 
" Volunteer work & meetings (mins per day)", "Social life & entertainment (mins per day)", 
"Sports & outdoor activities (mins per day)", "Hobbies & games (mins per day)", 
"Mass media (mins per day)", "Travel (mins per day)", "Other spec/not specfd (mins per day)"
), class = "factor"), value = c("7:30", "11:10", "11:50", "11:40", 
"10:50", "12:10", "11:30", "11:30", "9:50", "10:20", "9:30", 
"9:10", "9:10", "9:0", "10:0", "8:20", "9:20", "9:20", "14:40", 
"9:10", "12:30", "10:20", "10:30", "9:20", "12:40", "9:0", "13:10", 
"10:30", "13:50", "10:40", "14:0", "10:40", "12:20", "11:0", 
"11:30", "12:40", "10:30", "10:0", "12:0", "13:0", "11:10", "8:30", 
"15:40", "9:30", "12:40", "11:0", "10:30", "9:20", "10:30", "10:10", 
"9:40", "10:30", "11:30", "10:0", "10:20", "10:20", "11:50", 
"11:10", "8:0", "8:0", "12:50", "11:50", "12:50", "9:40", "9:50", 
"7:50", "15:0", "13:10", "13:50", "13:40", "9:50", "11:0", "6:0", 
"8:0", "12:40", "11:20", "13:50", "14:50", "9:40", "12:50", "8:30", 
"12:30", "13:0", "13:20", "9:30", "13:50", "14:30", "18:20", 
"9:50", "10:20", "9:40", "9:0", "12:40", "14:0", "12:30", "12:40", 
"12:10", "10:0", "7:50", "9:40", "12:50", "12:0", "9:20", "11:40", 
"6:0", "5:50", "13:10", "14:0", "11:0", "9:50", "8:10", "13:0", 
"14:20", "12:30", "11:0", "9:30", "9:40", "11:40", "13:0", "13:20", 
"9:20", "11:50", "11:50", "10:50", "15:0", "10:20", "16:0", "9:10", 
"12:10", "10:10", "13:10", "11:10", "12:50", "11:40", "12:20", 
"11:50", "9:50", "11:10", "9:10", "9:20", "12:0", "10:20", "7:50", 
"9:50", "11:20", "7:40", "10:40", "14:30", "13:40", "10:0", "14:20", 
"7:20", "12:50", "9:50", "12:20", "9:50", "15:10", "12:10", "12:0", 
"14:50", "13:0", "15:10", "9:10", "11:50", "9:40", "10:10", "10:50", 
"9:0", "11:0", "10:40", "9:20", "11:0", "11:0", "12:30", "12:30", 
"13:50", "9:40", "10:40", "12:50", "7:0", "9:10", "6:40", "12:30", 
"9:30", "13:30", "12:30", "14:30", "14:30", "14:30", "13:20", 
"10:30", "15:40", "14:30", "14:10", "12:30", "7:20", "9:20", 
"11:30", "12:0", "13:0", "13:40", "15:0", "14:10", "14:40", "12:0", 
"11:50", "11:40", "12:0", "9:20", "1:0", "8:0", "9:10", "14:30", 
"12:30", "11:10", "14:20", "8:0", "8:0", "7:50", "13:50", "7:50", 
"8:10", "9:30", "9:40", "11:40", "13:20", "10:0", "8:40", "11:20", 
"10:30", "11:40", "9:0", "12:50", "10:50", "9:50", "11:0", "7:20", 
"10:40", "9:20", "8:20", "7:50", "7:10", "9:30", "13:10", "9:0", 
"13:10", "8:40", "12:0", "8:40", "8:10", "9:0", "12:30", "9:10", 
"9:20", "9:30", "9:30", "10:40", "9:0", "10:20", "10:10", "9:20", 
"9:10", "10:20", "12:0", "12:40", "11:0", "11:0", "10:30", "15:0", 
"9:50", "11:30", "12:10", "11:50", "14:20", "11:10", "9:0", "10:30", 
"12:30", "14:40", "10:10", "10:40", "8:50", "10:10", "5:50", 
"11:50", "9:30", "10:50", "12:30", "12:0", "14:40", "15:0", "15:40", 
"12:50", "8:0", "10:30", "8:20", "8:20", "8:20", "8:40", "11:30", 
"9:50", "6:40", "8:50", "11:40", "10:0", "10:40", "13:20", "7:10", 
"15:0", "11:0", "13:40", "12:0", "14:30", "13:50", "14:20", "8:40", 
"13:10", "8:40", "9:40", "7:50", "12:0", "8:40", "13:20", "9:40", 
"10:0", "9:0", "11:10", "10:0", "9:50", "15:10", "0:0", "13:0", 
"10:20", "9:40", "8:50", "11:0", "9:20", "10:40", "9:10", "15:10", 
"15:20", "8:50", "11:50", "14:30", "13:0", "12:10", "12:30", 
"10:10", "9:40", "9:20", "9:20", "10:10", "4:30", "10:20", "9:50", 
"9:20", "7:50", "9:0", "8:10", "11:40", "9:0", "10:30", "12:20", 
"11:20", "8:30", "10:20", "10:20", "12:20", "12:40", "12:40", 
"13:30", "12:40", "15:30", "11:20", "11:40", "11:40", "10:40", 
"12:20", "10:40", "13:10", "15:10", "13:50", "13:20", "14:20", 
"13:30", "6:30", "6:50", "10:30", "11:30", "9:30", "12:20", "11:20", 
"12:50", "11:20", "13:40", "11:10", "13:50", "18:20", "12:20", 
"9:50", "6:30", "14:10", "12:10", "11:10", "12:50", "9:0", "7:50", 
"10:10", "8:40", "7:0", "10:40", "12:30", "12:20", "12:0", "10:20", 
"8:50", "11:40", "9:40", "10:30", "10:40", "11:40", "10:0", "10:10", 
"11:40", "11:30", "13:10", "11:40", "13:30", "10:50", "14:20", 
"14:20", "14:30", "13:0", "12:50", "11:0", "13:50", "11:50", 
"13:10", "11:40", "8:10", "12:20", "12:20", "10:20", "9:10", 
"14:20", "11:40", "9:40", "8:30", "6:50", "11:30", "11:50", "11:20", 
"9:20", "14:30", "13:0", "8:20", "8:10", "9:0", "9:50", "9:10", 
"9:50", "10:50", "10:50", "10:20", "9:50", "12:30", "12:30", 
"10:30", "10:20", "12:50", "11:30", "9:0", "11:40", "8:20", "11:10", 
"9:0", "12:50", "10:10", "10:40", "10:10", "8:30", "10:10", "11:20", 
"12:20", "7:40", "12:10", "14:50", "13:50", "7:10", "9:40", "9:20", 
"12:50", "12:10", "13:40", "14:10", "9:20", "11:20", "12:20", 
"12:20", "9:40")), row.names = c(NA, 500L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am doing following in R

```
 ggplot(melted_TimingOfActivities, 
        aes(x=variable, y=value), fill = variable)+ 
   geom_col(width=1)+ 
   coord_polar(theta = "y")+
   labs(x="Minutes", y="Activities", colour="Activties", fill="Activites" ) + 
   theme(legend.position="right", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0))
```

And I receive the following plot

[image]

Is there any easy way to format the minutes to show hours and minutes like

[image]

Comment: Your example data has 500 rows (presumably samples) of time for "Personal care/sleep (mins per day)." Are you looking for help in how to average these samples so you have a single value for each activity, like the example pie chart?

Comment: @JonSpring  yes, I would like to represent the duration of each activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's two steps to get there, plus an extra one to make the data more representative since your sample from the first 500 rows of your data only includes the first of 11 activities.

Step 0. Assign a mix of activities so the rest makes sense.

Step 1. Convert time to numeric and get the average.

Step 2. Plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(42)

# Step 0. Randomly assigning other values to "variable" so we have variety
activities <- levels(melted_TimingOfActivities$variable)
melted_TimingOfActivities2 <- melted_TimingOfActivities %>%
  mutate(variable = sample(activities, n(), replace = T)) %>%

  # Step 1. Convert text minutes:seconds into numeric, take average
  mutate(minutes = ms(value) / minutes(1)) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  summarize(avg_time = mean(minutes))

# Step 2: plot
ggplot(melted_TimingOfActivities2, 
       aes(x = 1, y = avg_time, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image]